# Python pandas cut first chars and past

Tags: python, pandas

I have, for example, 2 columns, I need a column no. 2 Copy the first 4 characters and paste up to column no. 1. to match Display column 1 and 2. In each processed header, they have different names, therefore, speaks column numbers

```
with pd.ExcelFile(file_in, engine="openpyxl") as ex:
    excel = pd.read_excel(ex, sheet, index_col=None)
```

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| item1 | ABC-1111 |
| item2 | BCS-2222 |

Expected result

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| ABC-item1 | ABC-1111 |
| BCS-item2 | BCS-2222 |

Can I use its number instead of Column Name?

```
(Iloc - dff.iloc[0] +=  dff.iloc[1].str[:4]
```

> IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.)

Comment: Can you add expected ouput?

Comment: To be clear, the formatted table you're showing here is an example *input*, or an example *output*? What should be the exact output, or input as the case may be, corresponding to that? Also, what happened when you tried to write code to solve the problem yourself? What logical steps do you imagine are involved in solving the problem, and where are you stuck?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - answer was edited by OP (and formatting by me), so voted for reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC Select first `4` values by `str` and add to column `A`:

```
df.A +=  df.B.str[:4]
```

EDIT:

If need select first and second column use:

```
dff.iloc[:, 0] += dff.iloc[:, 1].str[:4]
```

Comment: 54 sec ago user asked 18 sec ago you answered and 4 sec ago you said "Can you add expected output?"... what more to say.. +1

Comment: dff.iloc[0] += dff.iloc[1].str[:4]

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>


 IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.

Comment: @TMask - Use `dff.iloc[:, 0] += dff.iloc[:, 1].str[:4]` for select columns use `:`

Comment: @TMask - Solution above not working?